# Call IServiceScopeFactory.CreateScope() in a scoped service

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

What happens if I call `IServiceScopeFactory.CreateScope()` from a service which was already added as a scoped using `services.AddScoped`? Does it create a new scope and then a new instance of each requested scoped service when I call `scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService`?

The backstory:

I have got a legacy project from from another developer, and now I am trying to identify and resolve several bugs. First of all, I have something what looks like a database connection leak when using Entity Framework. I see this error under high load:

```
Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.
```

The thing is that, there are some scoped services which create a new scope and request a DatabaseContext, which is scoped by default in EF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IServiceScopeFactory.CreateScope` will create a new scope, entirely independent of any current scope. If you resolve a scoped service from the new scope, it will return a new instance of that service.

When you `Dispose` of that scope, all `IDisposable` services created by that scope should be resolved. If you're leaking scoped service instances, then it's worth checking that every `IServiceScope` created is also disposed of.