# Is CreateScope method in ASP.NET Core related with requests in any way?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, scope

```
using var scope = app.Services.CreateScope();
```

For example in this code, a variable named `scope` has lifetime limited by block in which it executes, or is it any way related to the request?

Because in .NET Core, scoped instances have same lifetime as each request. Sorry if I my question is bit confusing.

In this case does `CreateScope` refer to the scope of the executing method (or block)?

Comment: _”`IServiceScopeFactory.CreateScope` will create a new scope, **entirely independent of any current scope**. If you resolve a scoped service from the new scope, it will return a new instance of that service._ - https://stackoverflow.com/a/70865255/43846

Comment: _"because in .NET Core scoped instances have same lifetime as each request"_ - I would argue that you should not confuse .NET (Core) with ASP.NET Core. ASP.NET Core has concept of requests, .NET in general - does not (since .NET is not limited to web apps and not all apps have strictly defined request concept) and .NET build-in DI is not exclusive to ASP.NET Core.

Comment: [CreateScope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.iservicescopefactory.createscope?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0)"Create an IServiceScope which contains an IServiceProvider used to resolve dependencies from a newly created scope." Scoped objects are the same within a request, but different across different requests.